# How to find Processor class of an annotation in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations

Given a Java annotation, how can I jump to its Processor class (class extending the `AbstractProcessor` interface) in Intellij IDEA?

I tried full text search and find usage in project and libraries in Intellij IDEA, that is not working.

Comment: Define `processor`? Usage? And what do you mean by searching? Full text search or find usage in project and libraries?

Comment: @Peter thanks for your comment, the question is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellij Idea doesn't have something like find AnnotationProcessor for Annotation.

But you can do a two stage search.

First go to `AbstractProcessor` class, put the cursor on the classname and open `Find usage setting` dialog (don't know the default keyboard shortcut). Just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and type `find usage setting`.

Select `Derived classes` only and `Project and Libraries`:
[image]

The search result should find every annotation processor in your project and project libraries.

After that, you open the processed annotation and put your cursor on the class name and open the file usage dialog again.

But this time you want to find every usages and you want to restrict the search on your previous search result:
[image]

The result should contain every annotation processor that uses your annotation candidate. It's very likely, that it's only one.

This pattern can be used for every use case where you have a starting collection of files and want to refine/reduce the search result.

Comment: The two-stage-search is awesome. But it seems that the second stage cannot find reference in strings, like `@SupportedAnnotationTypes("lombok.*")`

Comment: Than just check the `Search for text occurrences` checkbox in the second stage search modal dialog.

Comment: Ok,.. I see. 

In case the link between annotation and it's processor is implicit via package matching and some sort of generic behavior in the annotation processor itself, I don't see a way to find that with "static" search commands. 

Reason: The link is done at runtime, so debugging is the only way to find that link. 
May this article help you to debug the build process: https://medium.com/@joachim.beckers/debugging-an-annotation-processor-using-intellij-idea-in-2018-cde72758b78a